# How to update a mass assignment model?

Tags: laravel-5

if I have a model `Student` and it has three properties:

1. name
2. age
3. classroom_id

`name` and `age` are in `fillable` array.

So if I want to create a new student and assign his/her classroom_id, I have to do this:

```
$student = App\Student::create(
[
'name'=>$request->input('name'),
'age'=>$request->input('age')
]
);

$student->classroom_id = 1;//for example

$student->save();
```

is this right? And if this is right, actually I do insert action twice, right?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can just update your `$fillable` array inside your model to include `classroom_id` and it will become mass assignable, meaning you don't need to do two inserts to get all the data in there.

As such, your `$fillable` array will look similar to this:

`protected $fillable = ['name', 'age', 'classroom_id'];`

And your create method similar to this:

```
$student = App\Student::create(
[
'name' => $request->input('name'),
'age' => $request->input('age'),
'classroom_id' => 1
]
);
```

This is the correct way, rather than running your insert twice which is unnecessary.

Comment: Yes, but if I don't want to let `classroom_id` fillable, I have to do insert twice, right?

Comment: @DengDeng well yes, because it isn't mass assignable then you cannot insert it along with other variables and would have to do a single insert specifically for it. why don't you want to put it in the `$fillable` array?

Comment: well, I just want to test it. For me, of course I will put it into `fillable`. Thank you very much.